# Palatino Linotype font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, preamble

The font family attached below is the Platino Linotype font (name from 'MS Word') italicized. Which latex command can be used to automatically generates the font family in math mode throughout the document? Thank you in advance.[image: Linotype font family (italicized)]

Answer (score 12):

## First solution: `mathpazo` (for `pdflatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

Text and math $ax+by+c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Second solution: newPX (for `pdflatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\begin{document}

Text and math $ax+by+c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Third solution: `mathpazo` (for `xelatex` or `lualatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}

Text and math $ax+by+c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Fourth solution: newPX (for `xelatex` or `lualatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}

Text and math $ax+by+c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Fifth solution: Pagella Math (for `xelatex` or `lualatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}

Text and math $ax+by+c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Sixth solution: Asana (for `xelatex` or `lualatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}

Text and math $ax+by+c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Comments

In solutions 3 to 6, the text font can be any OpenType/TrueType version of Palatino you have available, instead of TeX Gyre Pagella.

Comment: egreg, is there any reason to prefer one or another of the alternatives 3-6 for lualatex? Or are they equivalent?

Comment: @gusbrs Personal preferences; coverage for needed symbols; other factors.

Comment: I took a look at `unicode-math`'s documentation and it looks very interesting indeed, but since I don't actually use much math and the fact that it's experimental, I think I'll stick to `mathpazo` which I already used for pdflatex. And, if I ever happen to find a difference of coverage I need, I reconsider the case. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 5):

Reference: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newpx/

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}% LATIN MODERN TEXT, OR...
%\usepackage{newpxtext}% FOR PALATINO TEXT
% THEN...
\usepackage{newpxmath}% FOR MATH
\begin{document}
Text and $ax + by + c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So so grateful egreg and Stephen. Thanks a lot